# How to bind List<dynamic> to datagridview in c# windows form

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, datagridview, windows

My code is

```
List<dynamic> source=GetDatagridSource();
datagridview1.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
datagridview1.DataSource = source;
```

Here **GetDatagridSource()** return data in the form of List which having dynamic numbers of column.(Number of columns are not fixed).

I want to bind this result to datagridview1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this question is old but it might help someone looking to do this.

Create a DataTable from the dynamic object and bind the DataTable to GridView

```
public static DataTable GetDataTableFromDynamicObject ( List<dynamic> listData )
{
    DataTable table = new DataTable ( );
    if ( listData.Count > 0 )
    {
        var firstRow = ( IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, JToken>> ) ( JObject ) listData.First ( );

        foreach ( KeyValuePair<string, JToken> property in firstRow.OrderBy ( x => x.Key ) )
            table.Columns.Add ( new DataColumn ( property.Key ) );

        foreach ( var data in listData )
        {
            DataRow row = table.NewRow ( );
            var record = ( IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, JToken>> ) ( JObject ) data;

            foreach ( KeyValuePair<string, JToken> kvp in record )
            {
                row [ kvp.Key ] = kvp.Value;
            }
            table.Rows.Add ( row );
        }
    }
    return table;
}
```